# Regex python регулярные выражения

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка 1.000.000 нужно с помощью регулярных выражений автоматически добавлять thousand seperator для всех случаях.  Например 11.234    122   100.112

Comment: *добавлять thousand seperator для всех случаях*.... А как его добавить к `122`?

Comment: Когда 122 то нечего не нвдо добавлять только при 1.000 +

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Регулярное выражение: `\d(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))`

***Пример:***

```py
import re

string = '1234567'

res = re.sub(r'\d(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))', r'\g<0>.', string)
print(res)
```

*stdout:*

```html
1.234.567
```

Comment: Спасибо большое